# PL/SQL private DB link of other schmea: Possible to select but not to join

Tags: sql, oracle

I questions to understand Oracle and PL/SQL better.
The following example summaries my situation:

---

Three Databases: **Iceream**, **Cookie** and **Cake**

***Database Icecream***

Schema: **Icecreamread**

***Database Cookie***

Schema: **Cookieread**

Table:  Chocolat

***Database Cake***

DB Link (public DB Link to Icecream db as Icreamread): db_link_pub_icecream

Schema: **Chef**

Table: Milk (with select grants to roles where chef and confectioner are in)

DB Link (private DB Link to Cookie db as Cookieread): db_link_priv_cookie

View:  V_Chocolat as SELECT a,b from Cookieread.Chocolat@db_link_priv_cookie

Schema: **Confectioner**

---

I connect as Confectioner to DB Cake.

I can do successfully:  `select * from chef.Milk;`

I can do successfully:  `select * from chef.V_Chocolat;`

I can not do:

```
SELECT * FROM chef.Milk m
LEFT JOIN chef.V_Chocolat c
on m.a = c.a;
```

There I get the error:

```
ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found
ORA-02063: preceding line from Cake
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from Iceream
02019. 00000 -  "connection description for remote database not found"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I have the following questions:

1. Why can I select a View, which uses a private DB link to another DB?
2. If I can select, why can't I join?
3. Why do I is the db link to icecream mentioned in the error message if I don't query icecream at all?

I hope I made it somehow understandable.

Thanks a lot

PS: I suck at stack overflow formatting. If someone wants to tidy up, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Qualify the tables in the failing query with corresponding schemas and check again.  Actually you need to run the query under user chef for it to succeed.

Comment: I fully qualified them. And yes, if I run them as chef, everything is good. But I want to understand the behavior as confectioner.

Comment: Something wrong with the setup you describe. The error mentions database Iceream, which does not participate in the query, judging from your description.   Is the error actually the same with qualified tables?  Do preceding queries succeed under confectioner?

Comment: Icecream is only mentioned in the error message line 3. I do not know why because I do not query the DB at all. And yes, both selects work as Confectioner but not the join. This is exactly what I don't understand.